# Selenium IDE - verifyText in a multiple entries in a table (dynamically created ID's)

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-ide

The system should make a entry in the database (lets say a car with a registration number).
The box in the table with the registration number has ex. ID232 . I have no problem with verifying the registration number of the first car that comes up in the results (The verification is done based on a search which brings results from the database). The problem comes if I want to verify the next car based on reg. number , because the second registration number box has the same ID.
An example:

Car ID              Registration Number

1                  BS2344  <--- ID232

2                  BS3224  <--- ID232

The selenium IDE can verify the first entry, but the second verifyText will fail because it verifies the first one only (because the second box is has the same ID). The only difference is a automatically incrementing ID (Car ID) that I can use, but then i will have to input this manually (And the whole automation point is gone). The whole test process is to Create multiple Cars, and then verify them.

Answer (score 0):

use the loop and verify the same Id as many times as the entries in the database. as the car code is generated randomly, for the same id different car code will be generated and you will be able to check for all the ids..
I hope you got my point..

hope this answer would help you!